# Handling menu in dual pane fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-menu

I have a fragment layout like below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:baselineAligned="false">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/callsListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.MyCallsListFragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/callDetailFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.MyCallsDetailsFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The first fragment shows a list of all calls made and the second one its details. Each of them has a separate menu option.

Say callsListFragment has two menu items such as

```
View outstanding calls
Calls for today
```

callDetailFragment has three menu items such as

```
Edit call
Add new call
Archive call
```

I inflate those menus from respective fragments.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_mycalls, menu);
}
```

However, in the dual pane, I see all the five menu items which is rather conflicting as it is hard to find which one for which.

Is this the approach to show menu items? Could you guide me through the correct way of doing it?

The app is to support both tablets and handsets.

Answer (score 0):

Check is two pane mode when create option menu.

```
boolean mTwoPane = // isTwoPane ?

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   if (mTwoPane) return; // if (!mTwoPane) return;
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_mycalls, menu);
}
```

Or, Make new menu for two pane mode. (make resource folder like "menu-land")

Comment: I need both menu options. The problem now is since I inflate both menus to action bar, it comes up all together. But I need some other way of having two action bars (not sure if it's possible) one for each fragment. So the user knows which menu options is included in the action bar. Hope you understood!

Comment: Sorry, but Two action bar is not possible, one activity have one action bar.

Comment: I think you need more menu resources, and pick one in runtime.